# ASP .NET Blog Engine Web Installer API 

Tags: .net, asp.net, blog

For one project i need a blog engine that support multiple blogs (registered user can create their own blogs).
Blog engine has to be fully integrated with some existing system (users, roles, security etc.) so i need some good API, and if it is possible, blog engine must be developed in .NET.

Thanks.

Comment: did you Google??? there are hundreds of Blog Engines in .NET

Comment: OK, looks like you didn't understand me, i don't need blog engine i need something like  blog server. So that every user can create it's own blog, without additional deployment of the engine.

Looks like you didn't read my questions well, i said "(registered user can create their own blogs)"

Comment: The term for this is multitenancy (or a multi tenant capable blog) - I can't answer the question though.

Answer (score 1):

What about [BlogEngine.NET](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/)?

Answer (score 1):

1) Microsoft Web Platform Installer 3.0 (Web PI) is a free tool that allows you to easily install and run the most popular free web applications for blogging like Wordpress, dasBlog, and BlogEngine.NET with the built-in Windows Web Application Gallery. You can download this from: [Microsoft Web Platform Installer 3.0 Web site](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx). You can feature links directly to the webinstallers on this page and offer a tutorial for users on what to put in for settings to setup the blog under your servers.

A web-based installer creates a serious security risk on shared hosts because of file ownership. Anything your installer can write to is wide open to other accounts on the same server. You should drop the privileges after the installation.

2) Windows Installer XML (WiX) is a toolset that builds Windows installation packages from XML source code. The toolset supports a command line environment that developers may integrate into their build processes to build MSI and MSM setup packages. There's a tutorial available for customizing and setting up WiX  here:  [customizing and setting up WiX](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2011/02/23/web-application-installer-in-wix.aspx) and you can [download WiX here](http://wix.sourceforge.net/)

3) You can always ask your web hosting provider for the scripts they use to do the web installation of blogs from their control panel and then feature that script on your site.

Answer (score 0):

After one very quick google search you could try...
http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/

Answer (score -1):

I would answer with a StackOverflow Question

> [Best .NET blog engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408212/best-net-blog-engine)

Next time, please **Google it first**, you will get so many results, even all in **StackOverflow** and affiliates!

Comment: He's not looking for a good blog engine for .net.  He's asking about one that support multitenancy.

Answer (score -1):

Other says that blogengine powered by aspx is really good for blogging but most people say that wordpress is still the best and friendly blogging platform.

Comment: Wordpress is not .net based though, so wouldn't help in this case.